# Clean way for conditionally rendering HTML in view?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, struts

Is there a cleaner way to do this in a JSP/Struts1 setup ?

... some HTML here ...

EDIT:  In admin mode I would like to have access to additional parameters from a form element, 
e.g. from the form element:

```
input type="text" value="Test user" name="Owner"
```

EDIT 2: Actually, my problem is very similar to the question that was asked in : [Conditionally Render In JSP By User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935666/conditionally-render-in-jsp-by-user)

But I don't really get the "pseudo-code" from the likely answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `SessionConfig` exposed as a bean in your JSP (as part of request / session / Struts Form)?

If it's not, you can expose it. And if it's a static class containing global settings (which, by the looks of it, is a possibility), you can create a small wrapper and put it in the servlet context which you'd then be able to access from Struts tags as `scope="application"`.
Once that's done you can check your condition via Struts tags:

```
<logic:equal name="sessionConfig" property="adminMode" value="true">
 ... your HTML here
</logic:equal>
```

Or, if you're using EL / JSTL, same can be done via `<core:if>`.

Comment: currently, instead of sessionConfig is use MyFormIncludingConfigParameters

In the DynaForm I also have a property adminMode

It works, although the concepts are still a bit cloudy (what scope="application" means, how I coud trigger a non-DynaForm class)

Comment: scope="application" means Struts would look for a bean in ServletContext. It's a part of J2EE spec, you can read about it in Sun's tutorial. For non-DynaForm class, it either has to be defined as form in struts config (it will then automatically be bound to request or session as specified) or you have to manually bind it to request in your action; you can then use the above code replacing 'sessionConfig' with attribute name you've bound it to.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, it's hard to answer this, but I'd think instead of separate views: one for admin mode, one for normal mode. Extracting the parts of your pages into tiles will help you do this without a lot of pain; see: http://tiles.apache.org/