# How do I expose bean in JSP?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, web-applications, struts

How can I expose a Java bean to a JSP page by using struts? I know how to configure a StrutsAction to include a form-bean, but I wonder if there are other ways to interact with Java code from a JSP page? I ask this question because I don't understand fully a likely answer to a problem that I have asked here:

[Clean way for conditionally rendering HTML in view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444225/clean-way-for-conditionally-rendering-html-in-view/)

EDIT:

I understand that a JavaBean is defined as a class that contains mainly getters and setters for its properties. 
My problem was that I did not see how I can access parameters from Java classes in my JSP. Currently, I use a DynaForm to communicate parameters to the view. E.g. in the ActionClass I set the parameter, and in the JSP I can access it with

bean:write name="MyFormBean" property="myParameter"

My question was basically if there are other classes than a DynaForm class that can easily be accessed from inside the JSP with tags, and if so, if someone could provide an example.

Comment: Your question has been answered on the link you provided above. Again as pointed out by others, without much information, it's impossible to fully understand and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action class:

```
MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
myBean.setSomeProperty("someValue");
request.setAttribute("myBean", myBean);
```

In your JSP:

```
<bean:write name="myBean" property="someProperty" scope="request"/>
```

You can do the same with session as well. Note that you don't have to explicitly specify the scope in `<bean:write>` tag - if you don't, Struts will look in all scopes from page to application.

More information on scopes is available in [Java EE tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnafo.html#bnafp).