# Rendering different sections of jsp page based on user services stored in db

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

Does spring framework has any inbuilt feature to show different section to user based on services user has?

For example: if user has **service1** then show chat popup on right hand side of the page, else if user has **service2** then show comment box at the bottom of the page and don't render the right hand side chat popup.

Also, if anything changes in database at runtime, the same should reflect on UI as well without need to stop the server.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely, this question is an example of one of many ways you could achieve this: [Conditionally Render In JSP By User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935666/conditionally-render-in-jsp-by-user?rq=1)

Comment: yes, this  was what I initially thought. But how the changes done on db can be synced to ui. Example suppose we decide to swap the services i.e for service1 we will show comment box and for service2 we will show chat popup. 
For this to happen we also have to change the jsp/controller.
can the database alone drive service to view mapping, whiteout the changes required in jsp other than that for the first time ?

Comment: For what I think you're describing, I'd do something like: create a database table that links users to the names of the services they can use, then in my Spring controller I'd query that table for the current user, and add a list of views that the user is allowed access to to the model. Then, in the JSP, test whether each service is in the list, and, if so, display it. Bear in mind that this is a very simple, naive suggestion, and you'd probably need to make it secure and robust for production purposes, but I think this is the principle you're looking for.